# Expected End of Statement in formula with quotes

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2011

```
Sub FillNames()

Range("D2:D56").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Formula = _
    "=IF(AND(C>800,C<900),  "YES", "NO")"

End Sub
```

I get the compile error expected: end of statement. It seems to have issue with the quotes around the words YES and NO.

If I remove the quotes around YES and NO and run the macro, it will run and print what is in the formula quotes into the cell. I don't understand then how the quotes cause a syntax error.

I am running Excel 2011 for Mac, don't know if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: Add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module and let us know what happens.

Comment: all it did was separate the code into it's own code window

Comment: Sub FillNames()

Range("D2:D56").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Formula = "=IF(AND(C>800,C<900),  YES, NO)"


End Sub

Comment: that will print what is between the "" after the = into the cells, it won't function obviously, because it's not properly formatted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Double-quotes in strings need to be escaped by doubling them up:

```
Range("D2:D56").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Formula = _
                    "=IF(AND(C>800,C<900),  ""YES"", ""NO"")"
```

Comment: Firstly, Thank You. I'm sure that was simple for some.

Comment: Secondly, I thought I had tried that, but apparently I didn't do it right!