# Adding the " character as text in VBA

Tags: string, vba, text

Is it possible to add the " character as text in VBA? This character, I assume, is used to specify text in VBA, so when I try and add the following code, I receive errors:

```
Sheets("SalesDataSheet").Range("C5") = "=TEXT(B5,"mmm yyy")"
```

Alternatively, is there VB code which can execute the function I am trying to paste to the cell?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Expected End of Statement in formula with quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24173238/vba-compile-error-expectedend-of-statement)

Answer (score 0):

You have to double the quote to escape it:

```
Sheets("SalesDataSheet").Range("C5") = "=TEXT(B5,""mmm yyy"")"
```

Answer (score 0):

I also found this as a working alternative to pasting the code into the cell:

```
Sheets("SalesDataSheet").Range("C5") = Format(Sheets("SalesDataSheet").Range("B5"), "MMM yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a double quote (") in vba you need to type 4 double quote:

```
Sheets("SalesDataSheet").Range("C5") = "=TEXT(B5," & """" & "mmm yyy" & """" & ")"
```