# VBA Excel formula compile error - expected end of statement

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting a this error:

> Compile error: Expected: End of Statement

While trying to use an Excel formula in a VBA statement in the code below.

The error occurs on `"FIND("for ","...`

```
For i = 2 To lastRow
    aa = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(i, "A").Text                  
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(i, "E").Formula = "=MID(aa,FIND("for ",aa)+4,FIND(" ",aa,FIND("for ",aa)+4)-(FIND("for ",aa)+4))"
Next i
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expected End of Statement in formula with quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24173238/expected-end-of-statement-in-formula-with-quotes)

Comment: Try this  `"=MID(aa,FIND(""for "",aa)+4,FIND("" "",aa,FIND(""for "",aa)+4)-(FIND(""for "",aa)+4))"`

Comment: I'll add as a comment as the duplicate link answers the question.  Use `.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(RC1,FIND(""for "",RC1)+4,FIND("" "",RC1,find(""for "",RC1)+4)-(FIND(""for "",RC1)+4))"`.  `aa` is the text as displayed in column A.  `RC1` references column 1 (A) of the row the formula is placed in.

Comment: @RobinMackenzie but `aa` is a variable, you need to extract it from your formula by adding a `" & aa & "`

Comment: @ShaiRado - yes you're right - didn't read question properly:( I thought it was a named range.

Answer (score 0):

**It's a little long:**

You need to add the `"` inside your formula, I like to use the `Chr(34)` to add it.

So first, your `aa` is a varaible that changes every time you advance `i` in the loop, so inside the formula you need to break the constant part and add `" & aa & "` every time you use it.
But, you need to add the `"` to `aa`, that's why I modifed your `aa` line to:

```
aa = Chr(34) & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(i, "A").Text & Chr(34)
```

Second, I added a `String` variable named `Myfor`, and set the value to it `Myfor = Chr(34) & "for " & Chr(34)`, just to try to "shorten" the formula a little.

**Code**

```
Dim aa          As String
Dim Myfor       As String

Myfor = Chr(34) & "for " & Chr(34)
For i = 2 To lastRow
    aa = Chr(34) & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(i, "A").Text & Chr(34)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(i, "E").Formula = "=MID(" & aa & ",FIND(" & Myfor & "," & aa & ")+4, FIND("" ""," & aa & ",FIND(" & Myfor & "," & aa & ")+4)-(FIND(" & Myfor & "," & aa & ")+4))"
Next i
```